# Shift elements in string array to left to fill 'holes'

Tags: c#, algorithm, arrays

I have a list of names and phone numbers like so:

```
var phonelist = List<string[]> 
{
     new string[] {"Bill", "1234", "12345", "12314" },
     new string[] {"Bob", "", "12345", "12314" },
     new string[] {"Chris", "", "", "12314" },
     new string[] {"Dave", "1234", "", "12314" },
     new string[] {"Andy", "1234", "12345", "" },
}
```

What is the most efficient/elegant way to process this list so that the 'empty' numbers get filled from the right ?

Note, the arrays should stay the same length, like so:

```
var phonelist = List<string[]> 
{
     new string[] {"Bill", "1234", "12345", "12314" },
     new string[] {"Bob", "12345", "12314", "" },
     new string[] {"Chris", "12314", "", "" },
     new string[] {"Dave", "1234", "12314", "" },
     new string[] {"Andy", "1234", "12345", "" },
}
```

Comment: How come you have empty strings in the first place? Why not using List<List<String>> to store the phone list. THat way you wont have empty string problems

Comment: Good comment, my first reaction was 'not possible', but I'm going to look at the preceding code to see if it can be done...

Comment: @PoweRoy. Your comment is going to be the accepted answer, I fear. The only thing that is slightly 'dirty' is that I'm exporting to csv - so basically I get a jagged array, but Excel seems to handle that OK. I rejigged my code to work with lists first, then transform ToArray. Takes '0' milliseconds, where previous method was 2s!

Answer (score 2):

for each array cell, check if its empty and swap it with cell+1, if it's still empty swap it with cell+2.. when cell becomes not empty do the same thing with cell+2...

```
    int j;

    foreach (string[] strs in phoneList)
    {
        for (int i = 0; i < strs.Length; i++)
        {
            j = 1;
            while (string.IsNullOrEmpty(strs[i]) && j < strs.Length - i)
            {
                if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(strs[i + j])) // to not swap 2 empty strings
                {
                    strs[i] = strs[i + j];
                    strs[i + j] = "";
                }
                j++;
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: +1 for correct answer. Tho I'd use String.IsNullOrEmpty over == "".

Comment: There are plenty of sorting facilities in the framework... why not use them instead of a code which is error prone and hardly understandable ?

Comment: Marginally faster than @renatm (with my test data)

Answer (score 2):

```
public static void PutEmptyStringsToTheEnd(string[] array) {
    int j = 0;
    for (int i = 0; i < array.Length; ++i)
        if (array[i].Length > 0)
            array[j++] = array[i];
    while (j < array.Length)
        array[j++] = "";
}
```

Call this function for each List element.

Comment: Good thing I don't work with you: what is i and j? Why are you inlining a self-incrementing operator within an value declaration? It doesn't make things faster, if that's what you thought.

Comment: @orlandu63
i and j are indexes in the array. I'm not sure what did you mean in the second sentence, but I didn't intend to optimize anything. I just wrote code in a way that IMO is the simplest to read and understand. And I'm also happy that I don't work with you :)

Answer (score 1):

You could do something like that :

```
Comparison<string> comparison = (x,y) =>
{
    if (String.IsNullOrEmpty(x))
        return 1;
    if (String.IsNullOrEmpty(y))
        return -1;
    return String.Compare(x,y);
}

foreach (string[] array in phoneList)
{
    Array.Sort(array, comparison);
}
```

However you will need to tune the comparison logic a bit to keep the names before the numbers

---

EDIT : since the name seems to always be the first element, another option is to exclude it from the sort. No `Array.Sort` overload takes a `Comparison<T>` and a range, so you have to use a `IComparer<T>` instead :

```
class MyComparer : IComparer<string>
{
    public int Compare(string x, string y)
    {
        if (String.IsNullOrEmpty(x))
            return 1;
        if (String.IsNullOrEmpty(y))
            return -1;
        return String.Compare(x,y);
    }
}


foreach (string[] array in phonelist)
{
    Array.Sort(array, 1, array.Length - 1, new MyComparer());
}
```

Comment: This might work better if the last line of your comparison is return 0 - any two items that are not empty are considered equal and don't need sorting.  (Not tested this approach!)

Comment: This won't give the desired result.

Comment: Your code compiles but it *sorts* the arrays instead of shifting blank entries.

Answer (score 1):

This should work. I'm not that knownledged at C#, but the idea is there

```
foreach(string[] person in phonelist)
{
 string[] newPerson = {"","","",""};
 int index = 0;
 for(int i=0; i<4; i++)
 {
  if(!String.IsNullOrEmpty(person[i])) newPerson[index++] = person[i];
 }
 person = newPerson;
}
```

Comment: @Eric - I'd use !String.IsNullOrEmpty(person[i]) over person[i]!="" if i were you. Also you're making a second array, is this really necesary?

Comment: you don't need a pointer here, `newPerson` should be declared as `string[]`

Answer (score 1):

simple and ugly :(

```
    for(var x=0;x<phonelist.Count;x++)
    {
        var strings = phonelist[x];

        var l = strings.Length;
        var newAr=new string[l];
        var k = 0;

        for (var i = 0; i < l; )
        {
            if(strings[i]!="")
            {
                newAr[k++] = strings[i];
            }
            i++;
        }

        for (; k < l; k++)
            newAr[k] = "";

        phonelist[x] = newAr;
    }
```

Comment: Works, but slower than @renatm and @najmeddine

Answer (score 0):

```
List<string[]> sorted = new List<string[]>();

foreach (string[] entry in phoneList)
{
    List<string> nonEmpty = (from s in entry
                         where String.IsNullOrEmpty(s) == false
                         select s).ToList();

    int pad = entry.Length - nonEmpty.Count;

    List<string> pads = new List<string>();

    while (pad > 0)
    {
        pads.Add(String.Empty);
        --pad;
    }

    List<string> sortedEntry = new List<string>();
    sortedEntry.AddRange(nonEmpty);
    sortedEntry.AddRange(pads);

    sorted.Add(sortedEntry.ToArray());
}
```

Comment: System.OutOfMemoryException in your while :)

Answer (score 0):

This is cooler

```
List<string[]> result = phonelist.Select(per => per.OrderBy(txt=>txt.Length==0).ToArray()).ToList();
```